# Web API: Huge TTFB time difference for almost identical actions in controllers

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have some TTFB (pending, wait) problems with my Web API in Azure where I can not find the reason for, because both actions use the same mechanics for returning the results of a paged list

Controller "Post" => Posts as PagedList => ~ 70-100ms (~80ms in local dev environment)

Controller "Page" => Pages as PagedList => ~ 1.100-1.200ms (~80ms in local dev environment)

[image]

I have these problem within all of my 3 APIs where I work with paged lists. Some paged list actions works fine, some not. And it's always the same calls that work fast and always the same that work slow.

PagedList, based on Microsoft recommendation:

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    public PagedList(List<T> items, int count, int currentPage, int pageSize)
    {
        TotalCount = count;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        CurrentPage = currentPage;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get { return (CurrentPage > 1); }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get { return (CurrentPage < TotalPages); }
    }

    public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

        return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Pagination classes

```
public class Pagination
{
    private const int MaxPageSize = 50;
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    private int pageSize = 10;
    public int PageSize
    {
        get { return pageSize; }
        set { pageSize = (value > MaxPageSize) ? MaxPageSize : value; }
    }
}

public class BlogListPagination : Pagination
{
    public string SearchString { get; set; } = "";
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
}

public class PageListPagination : Pagination
{
    public string SearchString { get; set; } = "";        
}
```

Post Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostsAsPagedList([FromQuery]BlogListPagination paginationParams)
{
    var posts = await _postService.GetPostsAsPagedList(paginationParams);

    var result = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PostShortListDto>>(posts);

    Response.AddPagination(posts.CurrentPage, posts.PageSize, posts.TotalCount, posts.TotalPages);

    if (posts == null)
        return BadRequest();
    else
        return Ok(result);
}
```

Post Dto

```
public class PostShortListDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Abstract { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CategoryDto> PostCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Post Service

```
public async Task<PagedList<Post>> GetPostsAsPagedList(BlogListPagination paginationParams)
{
    IQueryable<Post> result;

    var posts = _context.Posts
        .Include(x => x.PostCategories)
            .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Category)
        .Include(x => x.PostTags)
            .ThenInclude(pt => pt.Tag)
        .AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paginationParams.SearchString))
    {
        var cleanSearch = StripInput(paginationParams.SearchString);
        posts = posts.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(cleanSearch) || x.Content.Contains(cleanSearch));
    }

    if (paginationParams.CategoryId != 0)
    {
        posts = posts.Where(x => x.PostCategories.Any(y => y.CategoryId == paginationParams.CategoryId));
    }

    if (paginationParams.TagId != 0)
    {
        posts = posts.Where(x => x.PostTags.Any(y => y.TagId == paginationParams.TagId));
    }

    result = posts;

    result = result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created);

    return await PagedList<Post>.CreateAsync(result, paginationParams.PageNumber, paginationParams.PageSize);
}
```

Page Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> PagesAsPagedList([FromQuery]PageListPagination paginationParams)
{
    var pages = await _pageService.GetPagesAsPagedList(paginationParams);

    var result = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PageShortDto>>(pages);

    Response.AddPagination(pages.CurrentPage, pages.PageSize, pages.TotalCount, pages.TotalPages);

    if (pages == null)
        return BadRequest();
    else
        return Ok(result);
}
```

Page Dto

```
public class PageShortDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Page Service

```
public async Task<PagedList<Page>> GetPagesAsPagedList(PageListPagination paginationParams)
{
    IQueryable<Page> result;

    var pages = _context.Pages.AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paginationParams.SearchString))
    {
        var cleanSearch = StripInput(paginationParams.SearchString);
        pages = pages.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(cleanSearch) || x.Content.Contains(cleanSearch));
    }

    result = pages;

    result = result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created);

    return await PagedList<Page>.CreateAsync(result, paginationParams.PageNumber, paginationParams.PageSize);
}
```

Startup

```
services.AddTransient<IPostService, PostService>();
services.AddTransient<IPageService, PageService>();
```

Although the call in the Post controller is more complex, it is executed over 10 times faster.

In Azure Diagnostics everything is Ok, no errors are shown. Ressources are fine too.

You can check the behavior here with these 2 GET requests in the browser or e.g. Postman:

```
https://kombasapicontent.azurewebsites.net/api/post
https://kombasapicontent.azurewebsites.net/api/page
```

At the moment I have no idea what the reason could be, because the behaviour is always identical for the requests.

**EDIT (debug output for the 2 requests):**

Posts => 33 entries in the db

Pages => 173 entries in the db

So we do not talk about "mass" data.

Posts as Paged List

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5011/api/post
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PostController.PostsAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Route matched with {action = "PostsAsPagedList", controller = "Post"}. Executing action komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PostController.PostsAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PostController.PostsAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content) with arguments (komBAS.API.Content.Models.Pagination.BlogListPagination) - Validation state: Valid
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.0-rtm-35687 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM [Posts] AS [x]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32), @__p_1='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [x].[Id], [x].[Abstract], [x].[Author], [x].[Content], [x].[Created], [x].[MetaDescription], [x].[MetaKeywords], [x].[PostType], [x].[ShowSocialSharing], [x].[Slug], [x].[Status], [x].[Thumbnail], [x].[Title]
      FROM [Posts] AS [x]
      ORDER BY [x].[Created] DESC, [x].[Id]
      OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32), @__p_1='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [x.PostCategories].[PostId], [x.PostCategories].[CategoryId], [p.Category].[Id], [p.Category].[Description], [p.Category].[IsVisible], [p.Category].[Name]
      FROM [PostCategories] AS [x.PostCategories]
      INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [p.Category] ON [x.PostCategories].[CategoryId] = [p.Category].[Id]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT [x0].[Id], [x0].[Created]
          FROM [Posts] AS [x0]
          ORDER BY [x0].[Created] DESC, [x0].[Id]
          OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
      ) AS [t] ON [x.PostCategories].[PostId] = [t].[Id]
      ORDER BY [t].[Created] DESC, [t].[Id]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32), @__p_1='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [x.PostTags].[PostId], [x.PostTags].[TagId], [p.Tag].[Id], [p.Tag].[Name]
      FROM [PostTags] AS [x.PostTags]
      INNER JOIN [Tags] AS [p.Tag] ON [x.PostTags].[TagId] = [p.Tag].[Id]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT [x1].[Id], [x1].[Created]
          FROM [Posts] AS [x1]
          ORDER BY [x1].[Created] DESC, [x1].[Id]
          OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
      ) AS [t0] ON [x.PostTags].[PostId] = [t0].[Id]
      ORDER BY [t0].[Created] DESC, [t0].[Id]
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action method komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PostController.PostsAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult in 58.0013ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[komBAS.API.Content.Dtos.PostShortListDto, komBAS.API.Content, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PostController.PostsAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content) in 72.2734ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PostController.PostsAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 89.6201ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Pages as Paged List (this is the slow one in Azure)

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5011/api/page
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PageController.PagesAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Route matched with {action = "PagesAsPagedList", controller = "Page"}. Executing action komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PageController.PagesAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PageController.PagesAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content) with arguments (komBAS.API.Content.Models.Pagination.PageListPagination) - Validation state: Valid
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.0-rtm-35687 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM [Pages] AS [x]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32), @__p_1='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [x].[Id], [x].[Content], [x].[ContentTag], [x].[Created], [x].[MetaDescription], [x].[MetaKeywords], [x].[NoIndex], [x].[PageType], [x].[Slug], [x].[Status], [x].[Title]
      FROM [Pages] AS [x]
      ORDER BY [x].[Created] DESC
      OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action method komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PageController.PagesAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult in 34.3177ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[komBAS.API.Content.Dtos.PageShortDto, komBAS.API.Content, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PageController.PagesAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content) in 44.738ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'komBAS.API.Content.Controllers.PageController.PagesAsPagedList (komBAS.API.Content)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 59.5634ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

**Update: Solved**

This problem seems to be related with the usage of Nlog in .NET Core 3.0.

Although the app was running and no errors were shown in Azure GUI, the logs show this error:

```
2020-01-07 12:08:12.3741|11|FATAL|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Hosting startup assembly exception System.InvalidOperationException: Startup assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup failed to execute. See the inner exception for more details.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The solution is to add

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup
```

to your project and the error and the delayed execution is gone.

I tested this in all my 3 APIs and it worked for all of them.

Comment: What query is sent to the database?  It looks like it might be expensive.

Comment: I added the debug log from my local environment for the 2 calls. The second one is the slow one in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to NLog and .NET Core 3.0 in Azure.

See the updated original post for the answer.